# paypal mobile express checkout

Tags: mobile, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to implement mobile express checkout using [this guide](http://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mec-itemPayment-website/)

I am first making a php call from my web server to call setExpressCheckout with required parameters, and getting back a valid token which I then use to reditect onto paypal using call

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_mobile-express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=EC-2BH4731318131920V

which redirects to PayPal but sandbox is telling me

`You have requested an outdated version of PayPal. This error often results from the use of bookmarks.`

If I call

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2BH4731318131920V

this is opening a valid PayPal page asking user to login.

Can any one please tell me where am I wrong or missing any parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using the standard _cmd=express_checkout and letting PayPal automatically detect the mobile browser and give the appropriate mobile view.